# Lock Sliding Up Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a sliding up with two buttons and I want to freeze the widget (sliding up) and unlock after the user taps on a button.

My sliding up code is here.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     color: Colors.white,
     child: _body(context),
   );
 }

 Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
     children: [
       Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: w(30)),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             SizedBox(
               height: w(15),
             ),
             Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/privacy_policy.json', width: w(150)),
             SizedBox(
               height: w(20),
             ),
             GestureDetector(
               behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
               onTap: () {
                 AboutDetailsPage.show(
                     context, FlutterI18n.translate(context, "about.privacyPolicy"), PrivacyDetailsBody(), true);
               },
               child: Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                 child: Text(
                   FlutterI18n.translate(context, "about.privacyPolicyUpdateDescription"),
                   style: textStyle17().copyWith(color: TecnoColors.theme().grey1, height: 1.5),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
       SizedBox(
         height: w(35),
       ),
       Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: w(15)),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Container(
               child: TecnoButton(FlutterI18n.translate(context, "about.privacyPolicyUpdateAllow"),
                   backgroundColor: TecnoColors.theme().blue2),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: w(15),
             ),
             Container(
               child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {
                   getUserBLoC(context).logout();
                   Navigator.pushReplacement(
                       context,
                       new CupertinoPageRoute<Null>(
                         settings: RouteSettings(name: 'LoginPage'),
                         builder: (BuildContext context) => new BoxLoginPage(loginPageMode.LOGIN),
                       ));
                 },
                 child: Text(
                   FlutterI18n.translate(context, "about.privacyPolicyUpdateDeny"),
                   style: textStyle16().copyWith(color: TecnoColors.theme().blue2),
                 ),
               ),
             )
           ],
         ),
       )
     ],
   );
 }
```

Basically if the user open this widget, the user can not close it, just after he taps on a button.
After the sliding up appears, the sliding up can not close, even if the user click out of. The sliding up can close just if user taps on one of widgets button

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you sliding up will WillPopScope and on will pop you can check if user has pressed the button the make

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

else, show some message